# Dagridview data validating winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need a practical example of row validating and error handling for the DataGridView. I tried to understand but I m still confused.
I have a datagridview1 with 3 columns ( start, name,date)
the user nemust be star  the first (start) column ( must not be empty and formated like this --> 8:30 AM)
second column name must not be empty and date must not be empty formated like this --->3/5/2012.
the entire row  must not be empty.

Thank you a lot

Comment: Be precise to u r problem and just asked the question with proper sentance formation so that it can be understood by others...

Answer (score 2):

you can start off by handling `CellValidating` and `RowValidating` events

In `CellValidating` you should be checking for the individual cells and check the limits say time should be in range of 06:00 AM to 06:00 PM sorts of thing.

`RowValidating` you can check if the corresponding cells and duly filled in and if not prompt for the user to enter the same.

In both scenarios you would need to set `e.Handled = false` with the appropriate message so the the user can verify and proceed with the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You may check this documentation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating.aspx